# Using an anti-cross-thread function to return a value

Tags: c#, winforms

I have this code to get around the bane of everyone's existence

```
delegate int GetSelectedIndicesCountCallback(ListBox thing);
private int GetSelectedIndicesCount(ListBox thing)
{
 if (this.InvokeRequired)
 {
  GetSelectedIndicesCountCallback d = new GetSelectedIndicesCountCallback(GetSelectedIndicesCount);
  Invoke(d, new object[] { thing });
 }
 else
 {
  return thing.SelectedIndices.Count;
 }
 return 0;
}
```

The return 0 being there because it'd error without it. However, it always returns 0. I don't know how to get it to return the other value.

Comment: "the bane of everyone's existence"?

Comment: @RenniePet Yes, this plagues everyone's coding and is by _far_ the most annoying exception you could ever think of.

Comment: Well, not that it really matters, but I think you're exaggerating. It only affects WinForms programmers who get into multi-threading, and it's a direct and logical and expected consequence of the Windows system architecture. (I'm in the process of learning Android, and it's the same there if you get into multi-threading.) Anyway, when I hear "the bane of everyone's existence" I think of things like death and taxes and politicians and regex and certain programming languages that I'll refrain from naming. :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The call to [Control.Invoke](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zyzhdc6b.aspx) will return the value of your method. All you have to do is cast it to `int` and return it.

```
return (int)Invoke(d, new object[] { thing });
```

Comment: Aha, this should do it. Thanks for the quick answer.

Answer (score 2):

When an invoke is required, you Invoke yourself and ignore the returned value.  This is why the compiler requires a `return` statement.

You should return the invoked results, as in:

```
return (int) Invoke(d, new object[] { thing });
```

Comment: You have to cast the result from object to int.