# Anti Cross Thread with function that retrieves a value

Tags: c#, multithreading

I've been googling around and trying some different approaches but none of them is working.

[Using an anti-cross-thread function to return a value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18394149/using-an-anti-cross-thread-function-to-return-a-value)

[Cross-thread operation not valid: Control 'textBox1' accessed from a thread other than the thread it was created on](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10775367/cross-thread-operation-not-valid-control-textbox1-accessed-from-a-thread-othe)

[C# Return value from function invoked in thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5182782/c-sharp-return-value-from-function-invoked-in-thread)

http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/188209-cross-thread-calls-made-easy/

My code (very briefly) is the following:

```
public partial class print : Form {

    ListView _listOfCategories = new ListView();
    delegate string getNameOfPrinterCallBack(string name);

     private string getNameOfPrinter(string name){
        ListViewItem search = new ListViewItem();

        if (this._listOfCategories.InvokeRequired)
        {
            getNameOfPrinterCallBack cb = new getNameOfPrinterCallBack(getNameOfPrinter);

            return (string)Invoke(cb, new object[] { name });
        }
        else {

            search = this._listOfCategories.FindItemWithText(name, false, 0);

            return this._listOfCategories.Items[search.Index].SubItems[1].Text;
        }
    }
}
```

And I call the function `getNameOfPrinter` in a timer (5 in 5 seconds). The first time it works properly, the second time and further it starts giving me the error:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.StackOverflowException'
>   occurred in System.Windows.Forms.dll

The line that prints the error is `return (string)Invoke(cb, new object[] { name });`

This happens because I'm trying to implement a way of avoid the error of Cross Threading. What am I doing wrong with my code?

Comment: As soon as `this._listOfCategories.InvokeRequired` evaluates to true you go into infinite recursion because you keep running `getNameOfPrinterCallBack(getNameOfPrinter)`. It is not clear why you are doing this, at first glance it looks like you should be doing the same thing you do in the else, just via a delegate.

Comment: You're right. I googled about that and I'm stuck into a infinite recursion. What do you suggest? My only goal with this is to avoid cross threading and return the properly String.

Comment: You are using the wrong kind of Timer class.  Make it a System.Windows.Forms.Timer and you can stop fighting the machine.   There is no point to, say, System.Timers.Timer, you are invoking anyway.  Nothing but grief.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved.

```
if (this._listOfCategories.InvokeRequired)
{
    getNameOfPrinterCallBack cb = new getNameOfPrinterCallBack(getNameOfPrinter);

    return (string)this._listOfCategories.Invoke(cb, name);
}
else {

    search = this._listOfCategories.FindItemWithText(name, false, 0);

    return this._listOfCategories.Items[search.Index].SubItems[1].Text;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are going into an infinite loop when `this._listOfCategories.InvokeRequired` evaluates to true (you are currently recalling yourself at that point, and `InvokeRequired` will always be true).

Change your pattern to something like below, which should help:

```
    private void OnSomeTimerEvent(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Action action = new Action(() =>
        {
            // Do your UI control item processing here. Don't recall this method!
        });

        if (this.InvokeRequired)
        {
            // or Use BeginInvoke if you don't want the caller to block (post the message 
            // onto the UI's message pump and will get processed asynchronously).
            this.Invoke(action);
        }
        else
        {
            action();
        }
    }
```